# CSS transition colors with jQuery and CSS only?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I see a lot of answers say to use jquery-ui `animate()` function, but this requires an import of an entire other library just to flip colors.

**Is there a way I can stick with just jQuery and CSS only?**

The problem: When I click a button, I would like another element to flash color to blue, then back to red (red is original color). Each time the user clicks the button, this color change behavior will repeat.

I have been able to get it to change colors to blue:

```
$(".my-button").click(function() {        
    $(".other-element").css("transition", "color .3s").css("color", "blue");
});
```

**Is there a way I can do the same for changing the color back to red? Something simple like:**

```
$(".my-button").click(function() {        
    $(".other-element").css("transition", "color .3s").css("color", "blue");
    $(".other-element").css("transition", "color .6s").css("color", "red");
});
```

... Where the element changes to blue after .3s, and then back to red after .6s? Note, the above code doesn't work, it only shows red (never changes to blue).

Comment: Your 2nd attempt doesn't appear to work as the 2nd line overwrites the first - you need to delay the 2nd call until the first has finished.  A *basic* approach would be to wrap your 2nd line in a `setTimeout(() => { .. }, 300)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose to do without third-party libraries at all. Here I create a css animation and with the help of a simple js code I add an animating class at the beginning, and then remove it at the end of the animation.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.my-button');
const other = document.body;

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  other.classList.add('active');
});
other.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
  other.classList.remove('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f00;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.my-button {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  transition: .2s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.my-button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.active {
  animation: bganim .6s;
}

@keyframes bganim {
  0,
  100% {
    background-color: #f00;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #00f;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="my-button">Click me</button>
```